# Do we close questions already answered on other sites?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, moderation, stackexchange

If a question has already been asked on another site, and over there it already has a great answer, or a collection of answers, do we want to leave it open here?

This specific question is the one that got me wondering:

- [Keyboard shortcut to decrease size of window?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383979/keyboard-shortcut-to-decrease-size-of-window)

More examples:

- [How do I turn on color syntax highlighting in the macOS terminal app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/383969/18101)

Comment: This post on SU also provides essential context. https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/is-it-okay-to-inform-users-to-stop-promoting-apple-se-when-a-question-is-fine-to